# Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: HTTP/2 error code: PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I get the following error when trying to connect to mongodb. I am running a spring boot application on java 1.8. Our company built a java client on top of grpc to connect to the mongodb and I see the following error occasionally. It doesn't happen all the time, but only occasionally. Any idea what that is?

```
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: HTTP/2 error code: PROTOCOL_ERROR
Received Goaway
Pseudo-header field ':path' found after regular header.
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
    ... 13 more
```